# How to properly use decorative fonts on a web page

Tags: web, typography, webfonts

I'd like to try some decorative fonts for a web site, like this one (just as an example):

http://www.dafont.com/nymphette.font

As usual, for the web one must verify the format compatibility of the font and licensing - no problem with that. The question is relative to the proper integration in a page without side effects. As you can see in the character table, decorations are mapped to regular characters - e.g 'A'. Let's suppose I want to use the decoration mapped to A; if the web page is consumed on a browser which doesn't support external fonts, of when the font is not downloaded yet, the decoration would be rendered as 'A', and it's confusing; a browser with accessibility support would probably speak the letter out loud, etc...

How to avoid that?

Thanks.

PS Of course it appear simpler to use plain image decorations. My question is not related to solving a problem, rather to experiment with this approach and understand how workable is.

** Update: I clarify that I know how to embed fonts in CSS, and I'm already using some "regular" (alphabetic) fonts from Google. The difference between alphabetic fonts and decorative fonts is that clearly you encode readable text with the former ones; you can minimize inconveniences during the loading by specifying fallback such as "serif", etc... With decorative fonts, you're using characters to represent graphics, hence my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can [embed fonts in your CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You might also want to look into the [Google Font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html) if you want some [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) with no learning curve.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I should have specified it - added an update to my question.